# Pass a selected bootstrap dropdown menu option to a Play framework Form

Tags: jquery, scala, playframework

I've inserted a bootstrap dropdown menu to my *file.scala.html* and I also have a script that displays the selected item as the button for the dropdown menu. Instead of text I use bootstrap icons.

Now, I want to pass the selected item to a `Form` which I pass to *scala.html* file but the only way I find to pass values is the `@helper.inputtext`

Here is my code:

```
<script>
$(function(){
  $(".dropdown-menu li a").click(function(){
    $(".btn:first-child").html($(this).html());
  });
});
</script>
```

---

```
@helper.form(action = routes.CategoriesInfo.save()) {
<fieldset>
    @helper.inputText(sampleForm("name"),'_label -> "Name")
    <div class="dropdown">
        <button class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" type="button" 
              id="dropdownMenu1" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" 
              aria-expanded="true">
            Icon
            <span class="caret"></span>
        </button>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenu1">
            <li><a href="#"><i class="icon-bank"></i></a></li>
            <li><a href="#"><i class="icon-mail"></i></a></li>
            <li><a href="#"><i class="icon-music"></i></a></li>
            <li><a href="#"><i class="icon-bus"></i></a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <br>
</fieldset>
<input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Save">
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of options

### Composition

Create a separate case class which is composed of the form, and a method/value which returns the selection. Then you have the option to define a method which gets the selection from the field (`def selectedItem`) or you pass in the selection explicitly (`selectedItem2`):

```
case class ComposedForm(form: Form[User], selectedItem2: String) {
  def selectedItem: String = {
    form.forField("name") { f =>
      f.value.getOrElse("No selection")
    }
  }
}
```

Then you can pass the composed instance into the view (this snippet is not completed, but it shows the relevant parts):

```
@(cform: ComposedForm)

@helper.inputText(cform.form("name"))

@cform.selectedItem
```

### Specialize (extend)

You can extend the `Form`:

```
class ExtendedForm(mapping: Mapping[User]) extends Form[User](mapping = mapping, 
    data = Map.empty, errors = Nil, value = None) {

  def selectedItem: String = {
    forField("name") { f =>
      f.value.getOrElse("No selection")
    }
  }
}
```

which is defined like this

```
  val extendedUserForm =
    new ExtendedForm(
      Forms.mapping(
        "id" -> Forms.number,
        "name" -> Forms.nonEmptyText)
        (User.apply)
        (User.unapply))
```

In the view (again, snippet is not complete):

```
@(eform: ExtendedForm)

@helper.inputText(eform("name"))

@eform.selectedItem
```

### Pass separate value

This basically leaves the form alone, you just pass the selected item as a separate value into the view.